# Access denied error in Facebook js code

Tags: javascript, facebook

For the past week or so, I have been getting sporadic javascript errors when using Facebook's js sdk code.

This is the error:

[image]

Here's the line of code:

[image]

JavaScript code from Facebook's site:

```
/*1345677565,173217057*/

if (window.CavalryLogger) { CavalryLogger.start_js(["p0usZ"]); }

if(!Array.isArray)Array.isArray=function(a){return Object.prototype.toString.call(a)=='[object Array]';};
if(!Array.prototype.map)Array.prototype.map=function(a,b){if(typeof a!='function')throw new TypeError();var c,d=this.length,e=new Array(d);for(c=0;c<d;++c)if(c in this)e[c]=a.call(b,this[c],c,this);return e;};if(!Array.prototype.forEach)Array.prototype.forEach=function(a,b){this.map(a,b);};if(!Array.prototype.filter)Array.prototype.filter=function(a,b){if(typeof a!='function')throw new TypeError();var c,d,e=this.length,f=[];for(c=0;c<e;++c)if(c in this){d=this[c];if(a.call(b,d,c,this))f.push(d);}return f;};if(!Array.prototype.every)Array.prototype.every=function(a,b){if(typeof a!='function')throw new TypeError();var c=new Object(this),d=c.length;for(var e=0;e<d;e++)if(e in c)if(!a.call(b,c[e],e,c))return false;return true;};if(!Array.prototype.some)Array.prototype.some=function(a,b){if(typeof a!='function')throw new TypeError();var c=new Object(this),d=c.length;for(var e=0;e<d;e++)if(e in c)if(a.call(b,c[e],e,c))return true;return false;};if(!Array.prototype.indexOf)Array.prototype.indexOf=function(a,b){var c=this.length;b|=0;if(b<0)b+=c;for(;b<c;b++)if(b in this&&this[b]===a)return b;return -1;};
if(!Date.now)Date.now=function(){return new Date().getTime();};
window.__DEV__=window.__DEV__||0;
```

My code:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'xxxx',
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));
</script>
```

My code does not do anything special. It's copied from Facebook's documentation.

Any ideas what's going on and how I can address the issue?

Comment: How do you even got the javascript error in visual studio?

Comment: @fastreload you can attach VS to IE. OP, Does it repro when you aren't attached? Does it repro in other browsers?

Comment: I've seen it in FireFox but haven't in a while. I'll use FF more often so I can try to catch it. Thanks.